# Yahoo OAuth 2.0 login malfunction

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

Today when I tried to access to my org SSO website using Yahoo OAuth 2.0, it failed and have the below behavior.

1. Initiate Yahoo OAuth flow, so it is now inside https://login.yahoo.com/config/login
2. Login page is shown, type in login name
3. Type in password
4. After loading for a while... It will go back to Login page in Step 2
5. Repeat `Step 2-3`

It was definitely working before without the above bug, anybody else is experiencing the same bug and/or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit on 10 May 2019,

The **Yahoo OAuth 2** login flow **is down again**, maybe wait a few months and it will work again...

---

Tested on 31 Aug 2018,

The **Yahoo OAuth 2** login flow **is working again**, probably Yahoo team fixing their bug.

Comment: Is this thing working for you now? I'm trying to make it work, but there is no xoauth_yahoo_guid in the "get_token" response like here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940949/yahoo-oauth-and-oauth2-0-login-malfunction. I wonder if this is just Yahoo bug or I may be doing something wrong?

Comment: Nope, Yahoo OAuth still down as of today (4/4/2020)