# yahoo oauth and oauth2.0 login malfunction

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-oauth

Users access our website using **Yahoo OAuth 1.0**,but it failed and have the below behavior.

1.redirect to  https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=XXXX

2.Login page is shown, type in login name

3.Type in password

4.After loading for a while... It will go back to Login page in Step 2
Repeat Step 2-3

It was definitely working before without the above bug

Then update our system use Yahoo OAuth 2.0
when we request  https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token
but sesponse not include '**xoauth_yahoo_guid**' field :

```
{
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

anybody else is experiencing the same bug and/or know how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah I am experiencing the same problem, but did you copy my question here? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836627/yahoo-oauth-2-0-login-malfunction) Seems oddly similar

Answer (score 0):

Tested on 31 Aug 2018,

The **Yahoo OAuth 2** login flow **is working again**, probably Yahoo team fixing their bug.

Also reference this: [Yahoo OAuth 2.0 login malfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836627/yahoo-oauth-2-0-login-malfunction/52111529#52111529)